# How to know what triggered an apk installation

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, rom-flashing, malware

I have been trying to solve a malware problem for the past couple days in a certain chinese phone (Android system version=6.0), the problem I am facing is that a malware keeps being reinstalled even after uninstallation, I have tried a couple of methods to no avail.

First, I tried uninstalling using the `pm` command, rebooted the phone and the problem was gone but as soon as I was connected to the internet the malware was installed again. I didn't want to touch the system at first so I tried to start a fresh and performed a factory reset. I tried using the internet again and I was back to square one, this time with more than 5 malware apps installed. I checked the installer package for the malware packages using `pm list packages -i` and all I got was `installer=null` so I couldn't get the app responsilble.

After this I was sure the problem lied within the system so I took fresh system images from 2 different factory ROMs and flashed them separately to the device each time performing a factory reset before switching the phone on and believe it or not when I connected to WiFi again the malware apps were still reinstalled.

I then tried capturing the traffic using [Packet Capture](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.sslcapture&hl=en) in hope to see what app was responsible for downloading the malware, for the entire time of the packet capture session (about 1 hour) I was using internet without seeing any malware, I stopped capturing packets and after a period of 5-6 hours of using internet the malware problem began again.
At this point I have really tried everything I know to spot the culprit app that installs the malware and I have run out of options, so is there really a way to get what process or app that caused silent installation of a package or should I just admit defeat and move on?

Here is a list of some malware package names:

```
com.yunshi.market
com.app.dov
com.glb.compass  
com.loee.lv 
com.androidapp.filemanager
```

Comment: Raw idea (untried): Capture the [broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7471652) for `PACKAGE_INSTALL` and `PACKAGE_ADDED` (should be [doable with Tasker](http://tasker.dinglisch.net/userguide/en/intents.html)), then let that trigger a logcat dump to file. Investigating that dump it should be possible to find what triggered the broadcast. As said, raw idea and not tried, so I cannot give a detailed step-by-step guide to it or guarantee success.

Comment: It might try then, but still keep its own records out of the log (still, it won't be able to suppress entries from other apps (here: PackageManager) unless having root powers.

Comment: I have a hunch that it might be a modified system app in `/system/priv-app` that is doing this but I have no way to verify it yet, as logcat seems to make the culprit app dormant somehow

Comment: Wouldn't it be strange that the very same app should be present in different ROMs? Unless those ROMs are all by the same dev, that is. Maybe you should [edit] your question and include which device, Android version and ROM it is about?

Comment: Have you tried identifying apps with permission [android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)?

Comment: What device, Android version and security patch date are we talking about? Older devices may have vulnerabilities in installed software that can allow a malware to hijack your device while browsing the net. In such a case you will not find anything malware-related on the device.

Comment: I think I might have found the apps(2 apps), I connected to the internet after factory reset, let the phone use internet for a while and then fired up PacketCapture and found an app named WirelessUpdate sending info like my imei, imsi and even wifi MAC address to a remote server, some other packets were GET requests querying for some apk file from the server, I checked its package name and found another similar package (both started with `com.adups.*` ) and came pre-installed in the stock factory system images in `/system/app`.There might still be some left but at least now the phone is usable

Comment: @Firelord don't apps with `INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission leave an installer package info to the apps they have installed?, these malware apps had null installer package

Comment: @AguThadeus not always. E.g. apps installed using Titanium Backup app would show null installer package. Please try my technique.